# Pulling data from database and displaying as hyperlink in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, hyperlink

Im developing an ASP.net application and Im having trouble finding out how to pull data from my database and display the resulting data as hyperlinks. Basically I need to pull the data and display it as a series of hyperlinks which when clicked will redirect the user to the corresponding page. Could anyone please point me in the right direction (tutorials,articles etc)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From your post I'd guess you have little to no html knowledge. I can't give you the technical solution without writing it for you but you need to retrieve the hyperlink value from the database and place these into hyperlink tags for your page.

I'd start here with html and retrieving the sql data: http://www.w3schools.com/

Answer (score 0):

Well without knowing exactly what data your pulling from the database, im going to take a stab in the dark and recommend the following.

Set up a stored procedure which retrieves the required information, then execute this procdure using a sqlDataReader and for each result stick some values within  tags?

So something like the following:

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
    string name= rdr["name"].ToString();
    string link= rdr["link"].ToString();
    HtmlAnchor htmlanchor = new HtmlAnchor();
    htmlanchor.HRef = link;
    htmlanchor.InnerText = name;
    formID.Controls.Add(htmlanchor);
}
```